# Create a Microsoft account programmatically

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, google-account, microsoft-account

I have an app that uses Azure Active Directory to authenticate and manage people. I need to be able sign-in anyone using their 3rd party accounts (Gmail, Yahoo, or any organizational account).

Can I register people into my Azure AD if they have a 3rd party account, which is not a Microsoft account yet? I know I can send them to https://signup.live.com/ where their account will become a Microsoft account. The question is if I can do that programmatically when they register on my site? How?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add multi domain user emails to Azure AD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352145/how-to-add-multi-domain-user-emails-to-azure-ad)

Comment: How about alternatives? Provisioning of some sorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I posted the question, Microsoft released a solution for that. It is called Azure Active Directory B2C. It offers connecting 3rd party accounts to the an AD. All major 3rd party accounts can become Microsoft accounts this way.

B2C pages are here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/services/active-directory-b2c/

Answer (score 0):

No. The concept of creating a Microsoft account for another user does not make any sense. How will the user know the password for the account? Microsoft Accounts are owned and managed by individuals and must be created individuals.

Comment: My questions is quite different. I don't need to know their password. I need to attach a 3rd party to my AAD. And for everyone else, Microsoft has offered a solution since I asked the question. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/services/active-directory-b2c/