# How do I add a Microsoft account to Azure Active Directory?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

When you adding a user to Azure Active Directory via the old portal you see this screen:
[image]
It allows you to add a user with an existing microsoft account.

I need to import many users with existing microsoft accounts. I'm planning on writing a powershell script to achive that.

How do I add an exising microsoft account to Azure AD with a powershell script?

[New-AzureADUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt757209.aspx) complains that "userPrincipalName" is invalid, as can be seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352145/how-to-add-multi-domain-user-emails-to-azure-ad). Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Azure PowerShell modules do not support adding Microsoft accounts to Azure Active Directory. The only way to utilize this feature is to use the old Azure Portal https://manage.windowsazure.com/

Comment: I wanted to do this today and had to revert back to the old portal to do this (as this answer suggests). What happens in a month when this portal is now retired?!

Comment: This has gone nuclear now that the classic portal redirects to the new one.  I read that there exists a powershell option for this but I haven't figured out the sequence of magical events to make that happen yet. If you have this problem please upvote this MS ticket: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/32766901-add-capability-to-add-external-users-with-existing

Answer (score 1):

This works using `New-AzureADMSInvitation`.

```
> Install-Module AzureAD
> Import-Module AzureAD
> Connect-AzureAD
> New-AzureADMSInvitation -InvitedUserEmailAddress 'test@test.com' -InviteRedirectUrl 'https://portal.azure.com'
```

Your output will contain an `InviteRedeemUrl` that the invitee should **open in a browser which is already logged in with their Microsoft Account**. There are other optional parameters that can be passed to `New-AzureADMSInvitation`. See the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadmsinvitation).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to import all of the accounts? Azure Active Directory supports B2B model.

B2B is based on invitation model which lets you enable access to your corporate applications from partner-managed identities. You can provide email along with the applications you want to share and send invitation to your partners, customers or anyone else who have account in Azure Active Directory. Azure AD sends them an email invite with a link. The partner user follows the link and is prompted to sign in using their Azure AD account or sign up for a new Azure AD account.

In my opinion you don't have to import users. More info here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2b-collaboration-overview/

Comment: When I did this today, I created a new *guest user* which then sent the invite to my Microsoft Account. Following the invite link, I was never asked 'which' account to use (Personal or IT Created)... I was just asked to create a new account with a new password, enter some PIN (that was also emailed to me). This then created a new account in the AD. Didn't allow me to use my existing MS Account.