# The object either is sourced from an on prem directory or is undergoing migration

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

I'm using MS Graph and Azure B2B to invite Guest users in my AD. For some emails it works perfect. But for some emails Graph API sends Bad Request response:

```
The object either is sourced from an on prem directory or is undergoing migration
```

Graph API endpoint

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations
```

Request Body Example

```
{
   "InvitedUserDisplayName":"TEST",
   "InvitedUserEmailAddress":"testemail@mail.com",
   "SendInvitationMessage":false,
   "InviteRedirectUrl":"https://google.com",
   "InvitedUserMessageInfo":{
      "CustomizedMessageBody":"TEST",
      "AdditionalData":{
         "@odata.type":"microsoft.graph.invitedUserMessageInfo"
      }
   },
   "Cc":"test@yandex.ru",
   "SenderName":"TEST",
   "SenderEmail":"test@mail.net"
}
```

Comment: This answer seems to indicate it could be something related to their AD Connect sync: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46972578/1658906. Maybe someone from the Identity team can shed some light on the situation where this error occurs :)

Answer (score 0):

Created ticket in Microsoft. They pointed that I had already these accounts added into my AAD tenant. So removing it fixes issue.